# How can we attract exterminators to the site?

Tags: discussion

The community seems to have a good base of knowledgeable folks when it comes to building and maintaining a home, but questions about exterminating various pests seem to mostly be answered by Google fu.

As pest control questions seem to be becoming more and more prevalent, what can we do to attract pest control professionals?

Comment: My company page idea might help for all businesses: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80834/need-feedback-on-company-page-idea not just exterminators.

Answer (score 1):

The first question to ask is, where do pest control professionals "hang out" online? Either personally or professionally (and no I don't mean business storefront websites).

Until we can figure *that* out, we can't really reach them.

http://www.google.com/search?&q=pest+control+forums

That has some likely candidates, places we should look to for perhaps a gentle nudge.

(omg it is so painful to go into phpbb world, but..)

- http://www.diychatroom.com/f51/
- http://www.contractortalk.com/f81/
- http://www.homegardenguides.com/garden-forum/pest-control-forum/

.. all have recent activity.

Comment: Visited the last link, and received a popup informing me that I won something or other! (hoping it was not a grand prize virus).